# How to list SVN tags and its revisions from command line

Tags: svn, command-line, tags, revisions

I need revisions of different tags. So far I used a Tag-Browser in SmartSVN. However it is quite slow.

Something like `svn ls "^/tags"` shows only the tags but no revisions.
And something like

```
svn log /path/to/tag -v --stop-on-copy
```

gives too much confusing information which is not needed.

Is there a svn command to get only tags and its revision?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can see the revision numbers of the most recent commit for each tag by adding the option `-v`:

```
svn ls -v ^/tags
```

If you want to process the results, I recommend using the command line `svn info --xml --depth=immediates ^/tags` and parsing the XML document with a script. For example, the following python script prints the names of the tags with their revision number:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys, lxml.etree
document = lxml.etree.parse(sys.stdin.buffer)
for entry in document.xpath('//entry[@kind="dir"]'):
    print(entry.xpath('string(@path)'), entry.xpath('string(commmit/@revision)'))
```